# django: access request.get_full_path from inside included template

Tags: django, django-templates

I am including templateInclude.html in templateA.html. While I can access {{ request.get_full_path }} from templateA.html, I cannot do so from templateInclude.html.

I would both like to solve and understand that problem. Is there a way of passing the request object to the included template?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Django version 1.3+, then you can use:

```
{% include "templateInclude.html" with full_path=request.get_full_path %}
```

For earlier versions, you should use `with` templatetag ie.

```
{% with request.get_full_path as full_path %}
    {% include "templateInclude.html" %}
{% endwith %}
```

In the both cases, just use `full_path` in the template which you will be including.

In general it works like context managers in regular python code - http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/

Anyway it's weird because according to the docs, included templates have access to the whole context of parent template. Check if you're using `RequestContext` in the view, or as a middleware.